# nginx replace given character globally in url

Tags: nginx, regex

I have a legacy backend wich doesn't interpret url-encoded `%2B` as a `+` sign in urls like

```
http://10.20.30.40/keyvalues?Name=foo%2Bbar%2Bbaz%2B...
http://10.20.30.40/keyvalues?Name=foo%2Bbaz
http://10.20.30.40/keyvalues?Name=foo
```

so I'm going to bring them to the form:

```
http://10.20.30.40/keyvalues?Name=foo+bar+baz+...
http://10.20.30.40/keyvalues?Name=foo+baz
http://10.20.30.40/keyvalues?Name=foo
```

with Nginx reverce-proxy. But I'm guess that in my case `ngx_http_rewrite_module`'s config wan't be so simple like [in the docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html), my current rule is:

```
    location ~ keyvalues {
        rewrite x2B +;
        proxy_pass "$scheme://$http_host";
    }
```

and it doesn't replaces (judging by the `tcpdump` and backend's responces).

What is the correct way to replace multiple characters in the url? (just like with the sed's `'s/%2B/+/g'` command.)

Comment: You cannot use rewrite. See [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/913130/316685)